# Still no way to filter by category in Control Panel?

Tags: entries, control-panel, filter

I'm wondering if, with the release of Craft 3.5, there is a way to filter by category in the control panel. I see this request goes back several years. The only workaround I can find is to use a Preparse field type to output the category name, and then I can at least sort on it. But I still can't filter on it.

This seems like a very fundamental thing that is missing from the control panel. Are there any plug-ins that handle it? And no, sorry, I am not writing my own.

Comment: Have a look at [Easy Search](https://plugins.craftcms.com/easy-search) it's not free but adds what you need and more...

Comment: Good idea. This plug-in has very few installs. Is anyone using it successfully?